# Cycles bake inverts a polygon on a normal map. A strange shadows with the normal map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, baking

1. I get a flipped polygon after Cycles bake.

**How to resolve it?**

2. When I apply the normal map I get the strange, sharp shadow on the border between dark side and light side of the cylinder.

Is it bad baking or very low polygon mesh?

**How to improve it?**

Link to .blend file if necessary:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After recalculating normal on the lowpoly mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), and shading it smooth rather than flat, I found only one small error remained, and it was caused by the light, not the map. so here is the re-baked normal map, but if you see a really sharp contrasting shadow, it's a different problem.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I just did it without recalculating normal and it worked fine... weird.

Comment: thank you, but I still can't get the correct normal mask.
Can you please tell your action step by step?

Comment: that is really weird... :/ I don't know how to help. It must be a Mac-blender bug, because it works perfectly on my windows *and* my linux